# What is the behaviour of the active set of blocks assigned to a multiprocessor?

Tags: cuda

Are these statements true regarding the behaviour of the active set of blocks assigned to a streaming multiprocessor (SMP) for execution, and what the Cuda programming model *guarantees*:

- When a block is assigned to a SMP, it will never be moved to another SMP once it begins executing
- If the kernel configuration limits it so there can only be N blocks in the active set per MP, then when all N blocks are in the active set of the SMP, it cannot remove or add any new blocks from/to that set until one of the existing blocks in the set has finished
- If a block within the active set continually spins, all other blocks in the set can still progress on the associated SMP

Copying shared memory and other execution state across from one SMP to another, or backing-up/restoring from global memory doesn't seem like it would ever be a good idea so I suspect the first two of these behaviours could be guaranteed by the Cuda programming model?

Comment: From this it appears an active block can potentially change SMP... https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/570978/visibility-what-thread-contains-to-what-sm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Blocks can move to different SMPs during [Compute Preemption](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-modes), which may be triggered e.g. by single-GPU debugging or context switching if more than one process uses the GPU.
- Again, Compute Preemption can invalidate this assumption. Theoretically blocks from a different kernel with lower resource requirements can also start execution on SMPs that are not able to launch any more blocks of the original kernel, although I am not sure whether that is relevant to you.
- While there are no guarantees about fairness, the throughput architecture of GPUs generally means that a spinning block will not completely prevent other blocks from making progress. The [`nanosleep()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#miscellaneous-instructions-nanosleep) PTX instruction may help reducing the impact of a spinning thread on other blocks further.

Comment: That's useful to know about the existence of nanosleep() too - although only available from Volta onwards.